# How to make the particular video view full screen in landscape if have two video view in my layout in android

Tags: android, android-videoview

I have two video view in my XML and always showing first video view only in landscape mode while change the orientation for second video view.

Thanks in advance.

Here my Coding for orientation changing:

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration aNewConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(aNewConfig);

          if (aNewConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {

            myOrientationButton.setChecked(aNewConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

            aPortraitHeight = myVideoView.getHeight();

            aPortraitWidth = myVideoView.getWidth();

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

            DisplayMetrics myDisplayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();

            getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(myDisplayMetrics);

            int aHeight = myDisplayMetrics.heightPixels;

            int aWidth = myDisplayMetrics.widthPixels;

            params.height = aHeight;

            params.width = aWidth;

          getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

            getActivity().getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

            myView.setLayoutParams(params);

        } else if (aNewConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {

    getActivity().getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(myVideoView.getLayoutParams());

            params.height = aPortraitHeight;

            params.width = aPortraitWidth;

            myView.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
    }
```